# Summary web usage of each process

Tags: process, monitoring, statistics

How I can check summary usage web of each process? I don't need summary of week or month etc. Only from start of a application. I would like to open application and application would be counting data until I close it:

```
Working 2 min:
Process                      Down     Up    Sum
/usr/lib64/opera/opera/      18MB   20MB   38MB
/usr/bin/owncloud/            2MB    1MB    3MB
```

It could show me PID or name it doesn't meter.

Comment: On which operating system? Should it be specifically Web (HTTP) or all internet access? Should it include all network access, or just the internet?

Comment: Linux openSUSE Leap, all network traffic without loopback